# DJANGO settings using namedtuple

Tags: python, django

I want to create a variable of type `namedtuple` in Django settings:

```
from decouple import config
from collections import namedtuple

SCHEMA_VERSION: namedtuple = config("SCHEMA_VERSION", cast=namedtuple(typename="SCHEMA_VERSION", field_names=["subject", "schema_id", "version"], defaults=[None, None, None]), default=None)
```

I'm using SCHEMA_VERSION in my RedisService class:

```
import aioredlock
import redis
import ujson
from aioredlock import Aioredlock
from django.conf import settings

class RedisService:
    _connection: Redis = None

    def get_avro_schema(self, subject):
        arn = ARN.avro_schema(subject)
        logger.info("{}: Locating {} in cache".format(self.__class__.__name__, ran))
        result = cache.get(arn)
        if result is None:
            logger.warning("{}: Mapping for {} not found.".format(self.__class__.__name__, ran))
            return None

        result = ujson.loads(result)
        result = settings.SCHEMA_VERSION(**result)
    def set_avro_schema(self, avro_schema, subject):
        arn = ARN.avro_schema(subject)
        logger.info("{}: Setting {} in cache".format(self.__class__.__name__, ran))
        cache.set(arn, avro_schema)
```

Where SCHEMA_VERSION is set in my SchemaRegistry class:

```
from django.conf import settings
from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient  

class SchemaRegistry:
    _client: SchemaRegistryClient = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self._client is None:
            self._client = SchemaRegistryClient(url=settings.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL)
            logger.info("{}: SchemaRegistry client started.".format(self.__class__.__name__))

    def deinitialize(self):
        pass

    def prepare_bytes_to_send(self, data, topic: str, method: str):
        subject = f"{topic}-{method}"

        avro_schema = RedisService.get_avro_schema(subject)

        if avro_schema is None:
            with RedisService.get_lock(ARN.avro_schema(subject=subject)) as lock:
                if not avro_schema:
                    avro_schema = RedisService.get_avro_schema(subject)
                if avro_schema is None:
                    logger.info("Calling Schema Registry for latest Avro Schema.")
                    avro_schema = self._client.get_schema(subject)
                    if avro_schema.schema_id is None:
                        logger.info(f"Schema for subject {subject} not found!.")
                        raise SchemaRegistryException

                    schema_for_redis = avro_schema._asdict()
                    schema_for_redis.pop("schema", False)

                    RedisService.set_avro_schema(ujson.dumps(schema_for_redis), subject)

        message_serializer = MessageSerializer(self._client)
        bytes_to_send = message_serializer.encode_record_with_schema_id(avro_schema.schema_id, data)
        return bytes_to_send
```

Where `get_schema` method looks like

```
    def get_schema(
    self,
    subject: str,
    version: typing.Union[int, str] = "latest",
    headers: dict = None,
    timeout: typing.Union[TimeoutTypes, UnsetType] = UNSET,
) -> typing.Optional[utils.SchemaVersion]:
    """
    GET /subjects/(string: subject)/versions/(versionId: version)
    Get a specific version of the schema registered under this subject

    Args:
        subject (str): subject name
        version (int, optional): version id. If is None, the latest schema is returned
        headers (dict): Extra headers to add on the requests
        timeout (httpx._client.TimeoutTypes): The timeout configuration to use when sending requests. Default UNSET

    Returns:
        SchemaVersion (nametupled): (subject, schema_id, schema, version)

        None: If server returns a not success response:
            404: Schema not found
            422: Unprocessable entity
            ~ (200 - 299): Not success
    """
```

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'SCHEMA_VERSION'`

Basically the problem is how to set Django settings variable using config() with type namedtuple.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please paste relevant code? (for example what exactly is `config`?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include one import. Now the edited post should give better readability.

Comment: What is `SCHEMA_VERSION` ? Is it a function or lamdba expression ? Why do you pass `**result` if it seems to be a regular assignment to a variable.

Comment: I edited the post one more time. The whole point of this is how to set Django settings variable using decouple config() with type/cast namedtuple.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the settings file with `SCHEMA_VERSION` defined? Maybe accidentally you are running some different file. Or, if you are working with docker, you need to rebuild the image? AFAICT, there is nothing wrong with the code above (in terms of django settings).